# Code reuse in different rspec contexts

Tags: rspec, code-reuse

I am trying to reuse some common code in a rails controller spec.  I have different contexts for admin users and regular users. However, much of the behavior is the same for particular actions, so I tried pulling that common behavior out into a helper function:

```
describe SomeController do
    def common_get_new
       # common stuff
    end 

    context "regular users" do
        describe "GET new" do
            common_get_new
        end
    end

    context "admin users" do
        describe "GET new" do
            common_get_new
        end
    end
end
```

This gives me the error:

> undefined local variable or method `common_get_new'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is common_get_new - setup stuff, calls to should, entire examples, something else?

Comment: @FrederickCheung It does not contain setup stuff. It has several entire examples in it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using [Shared Examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)?

```
describe SomeController do
  shared_examples_for "common_get_new" do
    # common stuff
  end 

  context "regular users" do
    describe "GET new" do
      it_should_behave_like "common_get_new"
    end
  end

  context "admin users" do
    describe "GET new" do
      it_should_behave_like "common_get_new"
    end
  end
end
```

Depending on what is in your `common_get_new` method in your question, in order to simply get rid of your error, you could put the method in **spec/support/utilities.rb**, or do as @Chris Heald suggested and define the method at the top of the file.

Comment: If anyone's looking for a way to pass a parameter into a Shared Example: 
`shared_examples_for "common_perf_test" do | name, message | `
`puts "#{name}"`, then invoke the Shared Example as follows:
`it_should_behave_like "common_perf_test", "#{description}", message`

Answer (score 0):

Try rearranging your contexts so that deeper contexts can share the same setup code:

```
describe SomeController do
  describe "GET new" do
    before do
       # common stuff
    end

    context "regular users" do
    end

    context "admin users" do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: My problem with this is that the stuff I am factoring out is not really setup work. Particular sections of the spec are the same in different contexts and I want to reuse sections rather than copying and pasting. Any way to do this?

Comment: Define your method at the top level of the file, not inside a `describe` or `context` block.